# Change user authentication settings type from registry

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, registry

I already change the value of the registry (using a c# windows application) (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Lockdown_Zones\1) "1A00" to "30000"(Hexa) equivalent to "Prompt for username and password ", and the change is done. but when i try to return the key value to the previous value "20000"(Hexa) equivalent to "Automatic logon only in intranet zone", in the settings table->customLevel->user authentication ->Logon the change is done , but when i open a new IE window the user authentication form is appear.
Can some one help me ?
thanks.

Comment: do you need to restart your windows before the change takes effect? also this question should be raised in serverfault.com :-)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to set an URLAction is to use the [SetZoneActionPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537086(VS.85).aspx) API. Writing the registry directly is not supported.

You shouldn't be doing this for the entire system if you want the behavior only in your application, however, you should instead implement an IInternetSecurityManager and attach it to your web browser control.

One of the problems you're likely having is that you're writing to the Lockdown Zones, which is very likely not what you really want.